# SQL Server equivalent of Oracle's utl_raw.cast_to_binary_double function

Tags: sql-server, oracle, data-conversion

I am trying to convert a function from Oracle to SQL Server.  The Oracle function contains a call to `utl_raw.cast_to_binary_double`.  I have searched SO, Oracle documentation, Microsoft documentation for an answer and cannot find it.

I am dealing with legacy data from a third party system, stored in a blob column, and my Oracle function converts the binary data into a hexadecimal string, then splits it into substrings, and calls the appropriate `utl_raw` methods to convert the necessary values.  In this case, I need to convert values like those below using `utl_raw.cast_to_binary_double`.

Sample values are:

```
BFF0000000000000 which converts to -1
40E43A8000000000 which converts to 41428
40E4640000000000 which converts to 41760
```

These values are julian dates which I then have to convert to an actual date-type variable.

My conversion application converts the blob field from Oracle into a hexadecimal string which is then stored in my SQL Server database.  I now need to replicate the functionality of the `utl_raw.cast_to_binary_double` function in SQL Server to complete my conversion.

Comment: I understand it correctly that that is the way Oracle encodes numbers internally... in which case since SQL Server encodes them differently there will be no tool to assist. I think you will have to read your values a byte at a time and manually apply the rules that Oracle provide on how to convert to a number. Why not make your conversion application do the complete job rather than half of it?

Comment: But your approach is simple "bass-ackwards" as we say in US. You should be using oracle functionality to convert to julian date at least (better yet - date) as you extract.

Comment: I hear you, and that's the way that I started: using my existing conversion function in the Oracle query.  For context, we are using a .NET app to bulk copy data from the legacy Oracle database to SQL Server.  When using the function to convert the blob to XML in Oracle, it takes several hours to transfer the data, during which I frequently get "end-of-file on communication channel" errors from Oracle.  When I changed the query to return the blob as a hexadecimal string, the transfer only takes a few minutes.  This is why I was trying to recreate the function in SQL server.

Comment: Also, there is much more data in the blob field than just the julian date.  All of the other data is converted correctly, I'm just having trouble with the ```utl_raw.cast_to_binary_double``` function.